# Have JS Office Add-in close or exit events for the document?

Tags: c#, ms-office, office365, office-addins, office-js

I'm currently develop a JS Office Add-in, but I could'n find any reference in API Documentation (https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/) for an close document or exit document event. I need to suscribe it to show the user warning   message about save plugin settings

Answer (score 2):

There are no events like that in the current version of the Add-in API.

Comment: OK, but, when will be available?

Comment: I think lots of people would love to know that. You can vote on ideas on [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/suggestions/11102253-expose-workbook-events-via-excel-javascript-api)

Comment: I post the comment to some one of that many people, but thanks, already voted in UserVoice

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
     var confirmationMessage = "\o/";
     (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage; //Gecko+IE
     return confirmationMessage;                            //Webkit,Safari,Chrome
});
```

Comment: But it doesn't mean, the addin is closed, it means that only html page will be closed. When user close the task panel, the event is also to be triggered.