# Can non visual Office Add Ins be created?

Tags: office-js

Is it possible to create an add in that simply responds to any document or email being opened or closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can [tell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36558311/have-js-office-add-in-close-or-exit-events-for-the-document) this is not possible with the current version of the Office javascript API. The feature for Excel is requested and in the [backlog](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/suggestions/11102253-expose-workbook-events-via-excel-javascript-api) for future development.